Why spreadsheet created by OpenXML 3.0 can't be read by OLEDB connection string for MS Excel 2007?
Does anyone know why a spreadsheet created by OpenXML 3.0 could not be read by OLEDB connection string for excel 2007? There are a few similar questions posted many years ago (using earlier version of OpenXML), but no real solutions. I am hoping after many years, there is a solution.
Simple spreadsheet can be created by the following code:
using (document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create("mySpreadSheet.xlsx", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
   WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
   workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
   WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
   worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
   Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
   Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Sheet 1" };
   sheets.Append(sheet);
   workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
}

It returns E_FAIL if using the following connection string (in C++) to read the spreadsheet.
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=%s;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;Readonly=True""
More information: if open this spreadsheet in Excel, do File->Save, then the spreadsheet can be read by OLEDB connection string. It seems Excel made some changes during the Save process, one noticeable change is it removed the prefix of namespaces in xmls (xmls are inside of mySpreadSheet.zip, which is renamed from mySpreadSheet.xlsx) created by OpenXML.
